# GetElementsByID() vs QuerySelector()

Tags: javascript

Researching a solution to the spotty IE support for GetElementsByID() and QuerySelector(), I got to wondering if there is not a process in JS similar to @supports (in CSS) that returns whether a method is supported by the user's browser.

Something like methodExists( "getElementsByClass" ) > true/false.

Probably not, but it would be nice.

Comment: There's no such thing as "GetElementsById()".  There's `getElementById()` (one element) and `getElementsByClassName()` and `getElementsByTagName()`.

Comment: Uh, `document.getElementById` is supported *everywhere*.

Comment: That should have been GetElementsByClass(), sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is `getElementById` and not `GetElementsByID`. Secondly, if you want to check support for any method, you can always check in [caniuse](https://caniuse.com) whether your browser is supported or not.

If you want to check through JS, you can always check if `document.methodNameYouWantToCheck` or `window.methodNameYouWantToCheck` ( based on where we can expect the method to be available ) is `undefined` or not. If it is undefined, then it is not supported.

Let me know if this answers your question or if you had some other query which I probably didn't understand.